# Changes required in my shell script in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, error-handling

following is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare pspath=""
declare user=""
declare password=""
declare password=""
for i in "$@"; do
  case $i in
  --pspath=*)
    pspath="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
  --user=*)
    user="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
  --password=*)
    password="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
  esac
  --ip=*)
    ip="${i#*=}"
    shift
    ;;
  esac
done

command="$pspath -username $user -password $password -ip $ip 

$t="sudo pwsh -Command "$command""
echo $t
```

command i'm running:

```
./test.sh --pspath=test.ps1 --user=test --password=test$123 --ip=0.0.0.0
```

output coming:

```
sudo pwsh -Command test.ps1 -username test -password test23 -ip 0.0.0.0
```

expected output:

```
sudo pwsh -Command test.ps1 -username 'test' -password 'test$123' -ip 0.0.0.0
```

can anyone help me here, please?
PS: command cannot be changed, so need to make changes in shell script itself.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can't change `--password=test$123` to be the same as `--password='test$123'` _after your script was already started_, because `$123` is replaced _before_ the user's shell starts your script.

Comment: Beyond that, see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describing why storing commands in string-type variables is intrinsically buggy, and what to do instead (short-form description: use an array).

Comment: Also, `$t=...anything...` is not a valid assignment.

Comment: what changes can be done to get the expected output?

Comment: If you can't prevent `--password=test$123` from being used in the invocation, the desired output is impossible, because the original password was already lost before your script started execution.

Comment: can we do something like following:
whenever any $ come in --password, when will place a backtick ` to escape $ as command

Comment: You can do something like `command=( "${pspath?mandatory option pspath not given}" -username "${user?mandatory option user not given}" -password "${password?mandatory option password not given}" -ip "${ip?mandatory option ip not given}" )` and then `echo "${command[*]@Q}"` to print or just `"${command[@]}"` to execute, but again that doesn't fix the `test$123` problem.

Comment: *whenever any `$` come in --password* -- no, because by the time your script is started the `$` is already not there anymore. You can't do anything "when you receive a $ in the password" because the $ is gone before your script is even loaded into memory; you never _do_ receive the $ in the first place.

Comment: wht changes need to be done in command

Comment: If the command cannot be changed, what you're asking for is not possible.

Comment: what are the changes need to be done in the command?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
./test.sh --pspath=test.ps1 --user=test --password=test$123 --ip=0.0.0.0
```

You wanted

```
./test.sh --pspath=test.ps1 --user=test --password='test$123' --ip=0.0.0.0
```

As written, you are passing in this password:

```
./test.sh --pspath=test.ps1 --user=test --password=test23 --ip=0.0.0.0
```

Once you've done that, the `$1` characters are lost forever
and cannot be reconstructed by the test.sh script.

Comment: what changes can be done in command to get desired output?

Comment: As I explained, you want to quote the password so the pair of `$1` characters won't be lost

Comment: ```
./test.sh --pspath=test.ps1 --user=test --password="test$123" --ip=0.0.0.0
```
like this?

Comment: I don't think you're reading the Bash docs. Try this: `FOO=abc; echo "x${FOO}y"; echo 'x${FOO}y'`. Now consult the docs on variable interpolation to understand why they give different results, and why that is relevant for your problem.